# regular expression error in DJango trying to find index numbers on blog.html

Tags: django, url, expression

I have the following error while trying to load up specific index numbers (relating to blog posts) using Django.

**The erroneous code is below** - can anyone help point out the error?

```
        path(r'(?P)<pk>\d+)', DetailView.as_view(model = Post,template_name = 'blog/post.html'))
```

**The whole code on that urls.py file to show context is here:**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post


#it's already going to blog/, so this regular expression is just blank

urlpatterns = [

        path(r'', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date") [:25], 
                                                       template_name="blog/blog.html")),

        path(r'(?P)<pk>\d+)', DetailView.as_view(model = Post,template_name = 'blog/post.html'))
```

]
**The URL I am trying to reach is:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2
```

**and the error on page is:**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
[name='index']
blog/
blog/ (?P)<pk>\d+)
The current path, blog/2, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Succinctly, I need help in finding the error in the following code snippet (the first path works fine, it is the SECOND PATH that doesn't)

```
urlpatterns = [

        path(r'', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date") [:25], 
                                                       template_name="blog/blog.html")),

        path(r'(?P)<pk>\d+)', DetailView.as_view(model = Post,template_name = 'blog/post.html'))

]
```

**UPDATE**
I changed the code to remove the erroneous bracket to this:

```
path(r'(?P<pk>\d+)', DetailView.as_view(model = Post,template_name = 'blog/post.html'))]
```

But it still doesn't work...

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
[name='index']
blog/
blog/ (?P<pk>\d+)
The current path, blog/2, didn't match any of these.
```

**Trying suggested answer**
I tried using this, but the error persists

```
urlpatterns = [

        path(r'', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date") [:25], 
                                                       template_name="blog/blog.html")),

                path(r'<int:pk>\d+', DetailView.as_view(model = Post,template_name = 'blog/post.html'))]
```

and tried this too:

```
path(r'(?P<int:pk>\d+', DetailView.as_view(model = Post,template_name = 'blog/post.html'))]
```

along with this:

```
path(r'(?P<int:pk>\d+)', DetailView.as_view(model = Post,template_name = 'blog/post.html'))]
```

**Errors persist**

```
  Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
[name='index']
blog/
blog/ (?P<int:pk>\d+)
The current path, blog/2, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are confused between the old regex-based URL mechanism and the new path-based one. If you use `path`, you should use the new special syntax:

```
path('<int:pk>', DetailView.as_view(...))
```

whereas if you want to use regexes, you should use the old `url` function (or the new alias, `re_path`):

```
url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)', DetailView.as_view(...))
```

Comment: Is there documentation on Django or somewhere else about this? Are you able to rewite the entire line correctly in this suggested new syntax so I can test it? Many thanks

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but an error persists> Please see update:

Comment: But that wasn't what I said to do at all.

Comment: Any chance you can be more specific with what to put in that line? :=) I am using the path-based syntax. Your suggestion (path('<int:pk>', DetailView.as_view(...))) doesn't include the digits or the ?P  - are you saying these are not needed to produce the same effect?